# Binary test file generator with checksum

Tags: c++, c++11, checksum, file-structure

In reading [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187812/parse-the-file-and-see-the-checksum-and-compare-it-to-the-last-4-bytes-in-the-fi), it occurred to me that it would be helpful to create test files according to the file format specification.  To recap, the file format is as follows:

### File format

Note that all numeric values are in little-endian format and the checksum is calculated over all of the file *except* for the checksum field.
$$
\begin{array}{l|c|l}
\text{name} & \text{length in bytes} & \text{description} \\
\hline
\text{file size} & 4 & \text{total number of bytes in file} \\
\text{person count} & 2 & \text{number of Person records in file} \\
\text{Person(s)} & \text{varies} & \text{sequence of Person records} \\
\text{zero padding} & 0..3 & \text{padding to make file size a multiple of 4} \\
\text{checksum} & 4 & \text{checksum of file as 32-bit unsigned values} 
\end{array}
$$

### Person record format

$$
\begin{array}{l|c|l}
\text{name} & \text{length in bytes} & \text{description} \\
\hline
\text{first name size} & 4 & \text{number of chars in first name} \\
\text{first name} & \text{varies} & \text{text of first name (no terminating NUL char)} \\
\text{last name size} & 4 & \text{number of chars in last name} \\
\text{last name} & \text{varies} & \text{text of last name (no terminating NUL char)} \\
\text{flags} & 1 & \text{flag bits: bit 0 = age field present, bit 1 = height field present} \\
\text{age}^* & 1 & \text{age in years. Optional field} \\
\text{height}^* & 1 & \text{height in inches. Optional field} \\
\end{array}
$$
An asterisk by a name field indicates that the field is optional.

### Questions

The code is mostly plain C++11, but there are a few features I'd like specific comment on.  First is the use of the [C++20 `std::endian`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian).  Is there a better way to do this?  Second is the use of the `static_assert` to assure that the iterator dereferences to a `Person` class.  Would  `enable_if` be a better way to handle this?  If so, what exactly would the syntax be?  Finally, I initially wanted to make this work with a single pass, but the checksum calculation was much cleaner by backing up in the file.  Is there an elegant way to do the same checksum calculation without backing up?

### maketest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>

// in C++20 we will have std::endian, but until then, we roll our own
#if 0
#include <type_traits>
#else
namespace std {
enum class endian
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    little = 0,
    big    = 1,
    native = little
#else
    little = __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__,
    big    = __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__,
    native = __BYTE_ORDER__
#endif
};
}
#endif

static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little, "Error: code is only intended for little-endian machines.\n");

class Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string &firstname, const std::string &surname, int age=0, int height=0) :
        firstname{firstname},
        surname{surname},
        age{age},
        height{height}
    {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Person &p) {
        return out << "{ { firstname : " << p.firstname
                    << " }, { surname : " << p.surname
                    << " }, { age : " << p.age
                    << " }, { height : " << p.height
                    << " }";
    }
    std::size_t length() const {
        return 9 + firstname.size() + surname.size() + (age ? 1 : 0) + (height ? 1 : 0);
    }
    std::size_t write(std::ostream &out) const {
        auto begin{out.tellp()};
        std::uint8_t flags{static_cast<std::uint8_t>((height ? 2 : 0) | (age ? 1 : 0))};
        std::uint32_t firstlen{static_cast<uint32_t>(firstname.size())};
        std::uint32_t lastlen{static_cast<uint32_t>(surname.size())};
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&firstlen), sizeof firstlen);
        out << firstname;
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&lastlen), sizeof lastlen);
        out << surname;
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&flags), sizeof flags);
        if (age) {
            out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&age), 1);
        }
        if (height) {
            out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&height), 1);
        }
        return out.tellp() - begin;;
    }

private:
    std::string firstname;
    std::string surname;
    int age;
    int height;
};


template<class InputIt>
std::ostream &write(InputIt first, InputIt last, std::iostream &out)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<decltype(*first), const Person&>::value, "Error: iterator to write() must dereference to Person class");
    std::uint32_t total_len{10 + std::accumulate(first, last, 0u, [](unsigned t, const Person &p){ return t + p.length(); })};
    std::size_t pad_len{4 - (total_len % 4)};
    if (pad_len == 4) {
        pad_len = 0;
    }
    total_len += pad_len;
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&total_len), sizeof total_len);
    std::uint16_t count{static_cast<uint16_t>(last - first)};
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&count), sizeof count);
    for (auto &p{first}; p != last; ++p) {
        p->write(out);
    }
    unsigned long pad{0};
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&pad), pad_len);
    out.seekg(0);
    std::uint32_t cksum{0};
    for (std::size_t i{total_len / 4 - 1}; i; --i) {
        std::uint32_t piece;
        out.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&piece), sizeof piece);
        cksum += piece;
    }
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&cksum), sizeof cksum);
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const std::array<Person, 6> people {{
        { "Abigail", "Adams", 6, 0 },
        { "Bob", "Barker", 40, 72 },
        { "Charles", "Cook", 0, 55 },
        { "Deborah", "Dawson", 0, 0 },
        { "Edward", "Electron", 45, 70 },
        { "Freddie", "Freeloader", 0, 0 },
    }};
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: maketest filename\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::fstream out{argv[1], std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::trunc};
    if (!out) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file \"" << argv[1] << "\"\n";
        return 1;
    }
    write(people.begin(), people.end(), out);
}
```

### Result

I used this command to compile, run, and examine the results:

```
make maketest && maketest test.in && xxd test.in
```

The resulting file, as displayed by `xxd` is this:

```
00000000: 9400 0000 0600 0700 0000 4162 6967 6169  ..........Abigai
00000010: 6c05 0000 0041 6461 6d73 0106 0300 0000  l....Adams......
00000020: 426f 6206 0000 0042 6172 6b65 7203 2848  Bob....Barker.(H
00000030: 0700 0000 4368 6172 6c65 7304 0000 0043  ....Charles....C
00000040: 6f6f 6b02 3707 0000 0044 6562 6f72 6168  ook.7....Deborah
00000050: 0600 0000 4461 7773 6f6e 0006 0000 0045  ....Dawson.....E
00000060: 6477 6172 6408 0000 0045 6c65 6374 726f  dward....Electro
00000070: 6e03 2d46 0700 0000 4672 6564 6469 650a  n.-F....Freddie.
00000080: 0000 0046 7265 656c 6f61 6465 7200 0000  ...Freeloader...
00000090: 15b1 8582                                ....
```

Note that this checksum does *not* match the one calculated by the code in the linked question.  It calculates 0x8285b**0**15 instead, which I believe is an error caused by that code's failure to account for inter-byte carry.

Comment: `enable_if` is primarily for situations where you want to enable different sections of code statically. It would be useful if you wanted to add support to run on a big-endian system. Barring that, your use of `static_assert` seems entirely reasonable to me.

Comment: I had some doubts about why you used 4 bytes for the name length, but now I realize there are names with 512+ characters long. Had to google for it. I'm not sure though if all of it is last name.

Comment: @Incomputable yes, if I were designing the file format, I’d do it differently. Not least, I’d use a CRC instead of a checksum.

Comment: @Edward, then are you interested in implementation that uses start and end blocks?

Comment: @Incomputable, if it's a better way to solve this problem and conforms to the given file specification, then probably so.  I'm always interested in learning better/smarter/faster ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assert seems a little bit off, it should be:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference, const Person&>::value, "Error: iterator to write() must dereference to Person class");
```

Why? In [input.iterators], N3797 (page 832), the table says that `*it` must be *convertible to `T`*. I'm too tired to pull out conversion rules from the top of my head, but I believe the way above guarantees that at least it will discard incorrect ones and not run into one of those dangling reference realms. This would be a great language lawyer question.

### When to use enable_if (e.g. SFINAE)?

As the title says, `std::enable_if` shall be used only in SFINAE context. If template instantiation doesn't pass enable check, and doesn't have anything to fallback into, it's gonna be just more cryptic `static_assert`. SFINAE is generally harder to get right, and tends to have small bugs that require very in-depth understanding of templates to solve.